# How to create a CSV file in day-by-day tabular form in R

Tags: r, csv

> Im trying to develop a way to Format a CSV file so that each day of the year has a value. Instead of having each row be the first of every month, I'm trying to find a way to have the same value every day for each respective month and then change when the values change. The way I made this table in its current form is I web scraped the ALFRED database and then used the write.csv function.

```
data1=get_alfred_data("INDPRO", "indpro", observation_start = "1860-03-01", observation_end = "2022-08-01")
data1
write.csv(data1,"Test.csv")
```

> the link below is a picture with an example of the output I have vs the output I want.
> if anyone has any suggestions I'm open to anything, just looking for a place to start.
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdKgu.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::expand` to add rows for every date and then `tidyr::fill` to fill in the missing values with the last observation. Something like

```
library(tidyr)
data1 %>%
  complete(date = seq(as.Date("1860-03-01"), to = as.Date("2022-08-01"), by = "1 day")) %>%  
  fill(indpro, .direction = "down")
```

Comment: Thanks that set me on the right track! I got an error for the seq command but it was fixed by adding a "by=1" argument. although now it tells me that the Column `indpro` doesn't exist. Any idea on how to get around it?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that we need a `join` in there too to use `expand`. Replaced with `complete`, and it should work.